# How do you profile a Drools application?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, drools, rule-engine

How can I find out how often each drools condition/consequence is being executed and how long it's taking?

The common JVM profilers are too low-level for this purpose, as the names of the internal drools methods won't tell you what rule they're executing.

Comment: Interesting question... Do you mean to have these statistics per each execution of your rule base or on a wider use of your application? [`AgendaEventListerer`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/event/rule/AgendaEventListener.html) comes to mind, but there might be better options available with pre-made tools.

Comment: Each execution. The working memory has several hundred thousand facts, and the first invocation of fireAllRules() takes +/- 20 minutes to complete on production hardware.

Answer (score 2):

The question is essentially impossible to answer for condition evaluation. Patterns and constraints on left hand sides are not evaluated a unit (in the sense a Java method is a unit) but as a network of expressions, evaluated in small instalments whenever it is necessary. Moreover, constraints occurring in more than one condition may result in the same code, eliminating multiple evaluation. The necessity of evaluation depends on the insertion, deletion and modification of facts; the effort varies depending on the values being in these facts. All of this is a consequence of the underlying algorithm, originally Dr. Forgy's Rete and, in Drools 6.x, Phreaky, which apparently makes the situation even less straightforward by improving efficiency.

Benchmarking the conditions might be done by inserting facts of one class while varying their field values and timing this (considering the usual difficulties encountered with Java). Note that even this is treacherous, as the effort may depend on the current state of the Working Memory, i.e., the values of the facts of other classes that have been inserted. And you have to consider the effort required to reestablish the initial state - leaving facts in WM will eventually cause increased overhead due to memory mangagement.

The situation is somewhat better for constraint evaluation. kaskelotti's hint on using an event listener is noteworthy; rather than trying to time these short intervals, just count them. Also note that it may be good coding practice for many Drools applications to implement the right hand side as a (static) Java method: these can be unit tested (and benchmarked) more easily.

Comment: "Impossible to answer" is really an exaggeration. Each of the expressions in the network belong to one or more rules; it should only take some simple math to associate the timings of each sub-expression back to the rules they came from. Counting events seems insufficient but better than nothing; I'll give that a try.

Comment: Admittedly, yes - you can answer it. But the answer will be useless for any predictive task. You can benchmark *this particular set of facts* in combination with *this particular set of rules*, but that's it. (I wrote my first rules for a RBS only 30 years ago, so you might look for a higher authority.)

Comment: That would be awesome. The rules don't change (between benchmarking and prediction), and the facts can be statistically sampled to provide a meaningful baseline.

Comment: This is a very much coarser look at things than the one for which you asked in your question. - If fireAllRules takes so long it is usually not due to condition evalution but to what happens in the consequence, and also to the way rules are subject to changes in facts. There's a wide margin for implementing things in the second-best way...